# Using Bootstrap row class but can't get 2 forms being one under each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to put 2 forms in a web page, but one under the other. Like this:

```
  <body id="Signup">


      <form class="row col-lg-6">

       <legend>Légende</legend>

          <div class="form-group">   
            <label for="text">Text : </label>
            <input id="text" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="textarea">Textarea : </label>
            <textarea id="textarea" type="textarea" class="form-control"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="select">Select : </label>
              <select id="select" class="form-control">

                <option>Option 1</option>

                <option>Option 2</option>

                <option>Option 3</option>

             </select>
          </div>
        <br>
        <button>Envoyer</button>

      </form>



      <form class="row">formulaire</form>


  </body>
```

As you can see both forms are using the `.row` class, but the are still inline when displaying the page.

I don't see what I am missing here.

Comment: Why are you using forms as element containers? I personally wouldn't and your problems will likely resolve themselves - either that or add `clear:both` to your css for forms - also, read up about bootstrap - `row col-lg-6` is nonsense - a row is a row, col-lg-6 is half the parent element width

Answer (score 3):

you are using `.col-lg-6` along with `.row` should be child, and then use `col-*-12` to have full width

also, you are missing `.container` as parent.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <form class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <legend>Légende</legend>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Text :</label>
        <input id="text" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="textarea">Textarea :</label>
        <textarea id="textarea" type="textarea" class="form-control"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="select">Select :</label>
        <select id="select" class="form-control">

          <option>Option 1</option>

          <option>Option 2</option>

          <option>Option 3</option>

        </select>
      </div>
      <br>
      <button>Envoyer</button>
    </div>
  </form>



  <form class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">formulaire</div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is a little strange. Your best option is to create div rows and columns. Then inside of the divs define your forms. However, the real issue here is that you applied both row and column classes to the first form:

```
<form class="row col-lg-6">
```

You can't do that, row and column must be defined separately:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `row col-lg-6` class from `<form class="row col-lg-6">` with `col-lg-12`

Answer (score 0):

You should make structure like this:

```
<body id="Signup" class="row">//"row" should be a parent to columns


  <form class="col-lg-12"> //width:100% or col-lg-6 for width: 50%

   ...

  </form>



  <form class="col-lg-12">formulaire</form>
```